# WMQ error : time out issue

Tags: java, ibm-mq

I am experiencing below MQ problem because of out of memory issue, still can't figure it out what is the root cause for this issue. please see the below exception and give some clues.

[10/14/15 11:10:47:817 GMT+08:00] 000010e5 ConnectionEve A   J2CA0056I: The Connection Manager received a fatal connection error from the Resource Adapter for resource qcf/qcfMORetry. The exception is: com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedIllegalStateException: JMSWMQ1107: A problem with this connection has occurred. An error has occurred with the WebSphere MQ JMS connection. Use the linked exception to determine the cause of this error.:com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: WebSphere MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2202' ('MQRC_CONNECTION_QUIESCING').
[10/14/15 11:10:47:882 GMT+08:00] 000010e5 SibMessage    W   [:] CWSJY0003W: JMSCC3034: The exception is ignored as no exception listener is registered: '
                       Message : com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedJMSException: JMSWMQ1107: A problem with this connection has occurred. An error has occurred with the WebSphere MQ JMS connection. Use the linked exception to determine the cause of this error.
                         Class : class com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedJMSException
                         Stack : com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.reasonToException(Reason.java:608)
                               : com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.createException(Reason.java:236)
                               : com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQSession.disconnect(WMQSession.java:758)
                               : com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQSession.close(WMQSession.java:718)
                               : com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsSessionImpl.close(JmsSessionImpl.java:498)
                               : com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsConnectionImpl.close(JmsConnectionImpl.java:295)
                               : com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnection.close(MQConnection.java:98)
                               : com.ibm.ejs.jms.JMSManagedConnection.destroy(JMSManagedConnection.java:1147)
                               : com.ibm.ejs.j2c.MCWrapper.destroy(MCWrapper.java:2054)
                               : com.ibm.ejs.j2c.FreePool.cleanupAndDestroyMCWrapper(FreePool.java:748)
                               : com.ibm.ejs.j2c.FreePool.getFreeConnection(FreePool.java:896)
                               : com.ibm.ejs.j2c.PoolManager.reserve(PoolManager.java:2879)
                               : com.ibm.ejs.j2c.PoolManager.reserve(PoolManager.java:2529)
                               : com.ibm.ejs.j2c.ConnectionManager.allocateMCWrapper(ConnectionManager.java:1499)
                               : com.ibm.ejs.j2c.ConnectionManager.allocateConnection(ConnectionManager.java:1011)
                               : com.ibm.ejs.jms.JMSQueueConnectionFactoryHandle.createQueueConnection(JMSQueueConnectionFactoryHandle.java:85)
                               : com.aviva.aol.messaging.adapter.MessageQueueAdapter.retryReceiveMsg(MessageQueueAdapter.java:234)
                               : com.aviva.aol.messaging.adapter.MessageQueueAdapter.sendReceiveMessage(MessageQueueAdapter.java:186)
                               : com.aviva.aol.integration.spi.TransactionProcessIntegrationImpl.jmsSendReceiveMessage(TransactionProcessIntegrationImpl.java:274)
                               : com.aviva.aol.tr.manager.FundIntegrationImpl.getFundCurrentHoldingListSwitching(FundIntegrationImpl.java:1961)
                               : com.aviva.aol.tr.manager.TransactionManagerImpl.getFundCurrentHoldingListSwitchingByAccountId(TransactionManagerImpl.java:887)
                               : com.aviva.aol.tr.action.TransactionSwitchPendingEditPrepareAction.doAction(TransactionSwitchPendingEditPrepareAction.java:193)
                               : com.aviva.framework.struts.CommonAction.execute(CommonAction.java:515)
                               : org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:431)
                               : com.aviva.framework.struts.StoryBoardRequestProcessor.processActionPerform(StoryBoardRequestProcessor.java:45)
                               : org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:236)
                               : com.aviva.framework.struts.StoryBoardRequestProcessor.process(StoryBoardRequestProcessor.java:104)
                               : org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1196)
                               : org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:432)
                               : javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:595)
                               : javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
                               : com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1214)
                               : com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:774)
                               : com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:456)
                               : com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
                               : com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:125)
                               : com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:92)
                               : com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter.doFilter(GuiceFilter.java:46)
                               : com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:192)
                               : com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:89)
                               : com.aviva.aol.common.servlet.XFrameXSSFilter.doFilter(XFrameXSSFilter.java:40)
                               : com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:192)
                               : com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:89)
                               : com.aviva.aol.common.servlet.XSSFilter.doFilter(XSSFilter.java:24)
                               : com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:192)
                               : com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:89)
                               : com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:926)
                               : com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1023)
                               : com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3703)
                               : com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:304)
                               : com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:962)
                               : com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
                               : com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:195)
                               : com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:452)
                               : com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:511)
                               : com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:305)
                               : com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:276)
                               : com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLConnectionLink.determineNextChannel(SSLConnectionLink.java:1049)
                               : com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLConnectionLink$MyReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLConnectionLink.java:643)
                               : com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLReadServiceContext$SSLReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLReadServiceContext.java:1784)
                               : com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
                               : com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
                               : com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
                               : com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
                               : com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
                               : com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
                               : com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
                               : com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1659)
     Caused by [1] --> Message : com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: WebSphere MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2009' ('MQRC_CONNECTION_BROKEN').
                         Class : class com.ibm.mq.MQException
                         Stack : com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.createException(Reason.java:223)
                               : com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQSession.disconnect(WMQSession.java:758)
                               : com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQSession.close(WMQSession.java:718)
                               : com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsSessionImpl.close(JmsSessionImpl.java:498)
                               : com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsConnectionImpl.close(JmsConnectionImpl.java:295)
                               : com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnection.close(MQConnection.java:98)
                               : com.ibm.ejs.jms.JMSManagedConnection.destroy(JMSManagedConnection.java:1147)
                               : com.ibm.ejs.j2c.MCWrapper.destroy(MCWrapper.java:2054)
                               : com.ibm.ejs.j2c.FreePool.cleanupAndDestroyMCWrapper(FreePool.java:748)
                               : com.ibm.ejs.j2c.FreePool.getFreeConnection(FreePool.java:896)
                               : com.ibm.ejs.j2c.PoolManager.reserve(PoolManager.java:2879)
                               : com.ibm.ejs.j2c.PoolManager.reserve(PoolManager.java:2529)
                               : com.ibm.ejs.j2c.ConnectionManager.allocateMCWrapper(ConnectionManager.java:1499)
                               : com.ibm.ejs.j2c.ConnectionManager.allocateConnection(ConnectionManager.java:1011)
                               : com.ibm.ejs.jms.JMSQueueConnectionFactoryHandle.createQueueConnection(JMSQueueConnectionFactoryHandle.java:85)
                               : com.aviva.aol.messaging.adapter.MessageQueueAdapter.retryReceiveMsg(MessageQueueAdapter.java:234)
                               : com.aviva.aol.messaging.adapter.MessageQueueAdapter.sendReceiveMessage(MessageQueueAdapter.java:186)
                               : com.aviva.aol.integration.spi.TransactionProcessIntegrationImpl.jmsSendReceiveMessage(TransactionProcessIntegrationImpl.java:274)
                               : com.aviva.aol.tr.manager.FundIntegrationImpl.getFundCurrentHoldingListSwitching(FundIntegrationImpl.java:1961)
                               : com.aviva.aol.tr.manager.TransactionManagerImpl.getFundCurrentHoldingListSwitchingByAccountId(TransactionManagerImpl.java:887)
                               : com.aviva.aol.tr.action.TransactionSwitchPendingEditPrepareAction.doAction(TransactionSwitchPendingEditPrepareAction.java:193)
                               : com.aviva.framework.struts.CommonAction.execute(CommonAction.java:515)
                               : org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:431)
                               : com.aviva.framework.struts.StoryBoardRequestProcessor.processActionPerform(StoryBoardRequestProcessor.java:45)
                               : org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:236)
                               : com.aviva.framework.struts.StoryBoardRequestProcessor.process(StoryBoardRequestProcessor.java:104)
                               : org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1196)
                               : org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:432)
                               : javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:595)
                               : javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
                               : com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1214)
                               : com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:774)
                               : com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:456)
                               : com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
                               : com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:125)
                               : com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:92)
                               : com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter.doFilter(GuiceFilter.java:46)
                               : com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:192)
                               : com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:89)
                               : com.aviva.aol.common.servlet.XFrameXSSFilter.doFilter(XFrameXSSFilter.java:40)
                               : com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:192)
                               : com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:89)
                               : com.aviva.aol.common.servlet.XSSFilter.doFilter(XSSFilter.java:24)
                               : com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:192)
                               : com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:89)
                               : com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:926)
                               : com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1023)
                               : com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3703)
                               : com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:304)
                               : com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:962)
                               : com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
                               : com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:195)
                               : com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:452)
                               : com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:511)
                               : com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:305)
                               : com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:276)
                               : com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLConnectionLink.determineNextChannel(SSLConnectionLink.java:1049)
                               : com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLConnectionLink$MyReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLConnectionLink.java:643)
                               : com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLReadServiceContext$SSLReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLReadServiceContext.java:1784)
                               : com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
                               : com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
                               : com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
                               : com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
                               : com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
                               : com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
                               : com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
                               : com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1659)
     Caused by [2] --> Message : com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException: CC=2;RC=2009
                         Class : class com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException
                         Stack : com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.internal.RemoteHconn.enterCall(RemoteHconn.java:475)
                               : com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.internal.RemoteHconn.enterCall(RemoteHconn.java:397)
                               : com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.internal.RemoteHconn.enterCall(RemoteHconn.java:372)
                               : com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.internal.RemoteFAP.MQDISC(RemoteFAP.java:2604)
                               : com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQSession.disconnect(WMQSession.java:746)
                               : com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQSession.close(WMQSession.java:718)
                               : com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsSessionImpl.close(JmsSessionImpl.java:498)
                               : com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsConnectionImpl.close(JmsConnectionImpl.java:295)
                               : com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnection.close(MQConnection.java:98)
                               : com.ibm.ejs.jms.JMSManagedConnection.destroy(JMSManagedConnection.java:1147)
                               : com.ibm.ejs.j2c.MCWrapper.destroy(MCWrapper.java:2054)
                               : com.ibm.ejs.j2c.FreePool.cleanupAndDestroyMCWrapper(FreePool.java:748)
                               : com.ibm.ejs.j2c.FreePool.getFreeConnection(FreePool.java:896)
                               : com.ibm.ejs.j2c.PoolManager.reserve(PoolManager.java:2879)
                               : com.ibm.ejs.j2c.PoolManager.reserve(PoolManager.java:2529)
                               : com.ibm.ejs.j2c.ConnectionManager.allocateMCWrapper(ConnectionManager.java:1499)
                               : com.ibm.ejs.j2c.ConnectionManager.allocateConnection(ConnectionManager.java:1011)
                               : com.ibm.ejs.jms.JMSQueueConnectionFactoryHandle.createQueueConnection(JMSQueueConnectionFactoryHandle.java:85)
                               : com.aviva.aol.messaging.adapter.MessageQueueAdapter.retryReceiveMsg(MessageQueueAdapter.java:234)
                               : com.aviva.aol.messaging.adapter.MessageQueueAdapter.sendReceiveMessage(MessageQueueAdapter.java:186)
                               : com.aviva.aol.integration.spi.TransactionProcessIntegrationImpl.jmsSendReceiveMessage(TransactionProcessIntegrationImpl.java:274)
                               : com.aviva.aol.tr.manager.FundIntegrationImpl.getFundCurrentHoldingListSwitching(FundIntegrationImpl.java:1961)
                               : com.aviva.aol.tr.manager.TransactionManagerImpl.getFundCurrentHoldingListSwitchingByAccountId(TransactionManagerImpl.java:887)
                               : com.aviva.aol.tr.action.TransactionSwitchPendingEditPrepareAction.doAction(TransactionSwitchPendingEditPrepareAction.java:193)
                               : com.aviva.framework.struts.CommonAction.execute(CommonAction.java:515)
                               : org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:431)
                               : com.aviva.framework.struts.StoryBoardRequestProcessor.processActionPerform(StoryBoardRequestProcessor.java:45)
                               : org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:236)
                               : com.aviva.framework.struts.StoryBoardRequestProcessor.process(StoryBoardRequestProcessor.java:104)
                               : org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1196)
                               : org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:432)
                               : javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:595)
                               : javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
                               : com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1214)
                               : com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:774)
                               : com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:456)
                               : com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
                               : com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:125)
                               : com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:92)
                               : com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter.doFilter(GuiceFilter.java:46)
                               : com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:192)
                               : com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:89)
                               : com.aviva.aol.common.servlet.XFrameXSSFilter.doFilter(XFrameXSSFilter.java:40)
                               : com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:192)
                               : com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:89)
                               : com.aviva.aol.common.servlet.XSSFilter.doFilter(XSSFilter.java:24)
                               : com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:192)
                               : com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:89)
                               : com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:926)
                               : com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1023)
                               : com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3703)
                               : com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:304)
                               : com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:962)
                               : com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
                               : com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:195)
                               : com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:452)
                               : com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:511)
                               : com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:305)
                               : com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:276)
                               : com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLConnectionLink.determineNextChannel(SSLConnectionLink.java:1049)
                               : com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLConnectionLink$MyReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLConnectionLink.java:643)
                               : com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLReadServiceContext$SSLReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLReadServiceContext.java:1784)
                               : com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
                               : com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
                              : com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
                               : com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
                               : com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
                               : com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
                               : com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
                               : com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1659)
     Caused by [3] --> Message : com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException: CC=2;RC=2195
                         Class : class com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException
                         Stack : com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.internal.RemoteRcvThread.run(RemoteRcvThread.java:597)
                               : com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.workqueue.WorkQueueItem.runTask(WorkQueueItem.java:209)
                               : com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.workqueue.SimpleWorkQueueItem.runItem(SimpleWorkQueueItem.java:100)
                               : com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.workqueue.WorkQueueItem.run(WorkQueueItem.java:224)
                               : **com.ibm.ws.wmqcsi.workqueue.WorkQueueManagerImpl$WorkQueueRunnable.run(WorkQueueManagerImpl.java:550)
                               : java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:769)
     Caused by [4] --> Message : java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
                         Class : class java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
                         Stack :** com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.internal.system.RemoteCommsBufferItem.(RemoteCommsBufferItem.java:84)
                               : com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.internal.system.RemoteCommsBufferPool.allocBuffer(RemoteCommsBufferPool.java:107)
                               : com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.internal.RemoteRcvThread.receiveOneTSH(RemoteRcvThread.java:709)
                               : com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.internal.RemoteRcvThread.run(RemoteRcvThread.java:151)
                               : com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.workqueue.WorkQueueItem.runTask(WorkQueueItem.java:209)
                               : com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.workqueue.SimpleWorkQueueItem.runItem(SimpleWorkQueueItem.java:100)
                               : com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.workqueue.WorkQueueItem.run(WorkQueueItem.java:224)
                               : com.ibm.ws.wmqcsi.workqueue.WorkQueueManagerImpl$WorkQueueRunnable.run(WorkQueueManagerImpl.java:550)
                               : java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:769)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause is that either the channel or the queue manager you are connecting to is being stopped:
compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2202' ('MQRC_CONNECTION_QUIESCING')